# sort search results alphabetically

Tags: php, arrays, file, sorting, search

```
<?php
$searchforfile = "les thugs - 1999 - tout doit disparaitre (lp)  [www.pirate-punk.net].zip";

    $root = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
    $search = preg_quote(utf8_decode($searchforfile));


        function rsearch($folder, $pattern) {
            $dir = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($folder);
            $ite = new RecursiveIteratorIterator($dir);
            $files = new RegexIterator($ite, $pattern, RegexIterator::GET_MATCH);
            $fileList = array();

            foreach($files as $file) {
                $fileList = array_merge($fileList, $file);
            }
            return $fileList;
        }
        $resultatss = rsearch($root, '/.*\/'.$search.'/');

foreach ($resultatss as $resultat) {

        $downloadlink = str_replace("$root/", "", $resultat);
            $za = new ZipArchive();
            $za->open($downloadlink);
            for( $i = 0; $i < $za->numFiles; $i++ ){
                $stat = $za->statIndex( $i );
                $toune = basename( $stat['name'] );
                echo "$toune <br>";
            }


}

?>
```

This script will list all files inside a ZIP archive then echo the name of each files.

Now i'm having some trouble figuring how to sort the files names ($toune) alphabetically

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `asort` like

```
for( $i = 0; $i < $za->numFiles; $i++ ){
    $stat = $za->statIndex( $i );
    $toune_arr[] = basename( $stat['name'] );        
}
asort($toune_arr);
print_r($toune_arr);
```

See this [**LINK**](http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)